# Function within a function can't be called upon outside of the function

Tags: python

I have two functions called Play1() and play2() in the class Player that both call upon functions that lay under the same function. The computer can't find the function play1() or play2() when I try calling them from outside the class by using "Player.Play1()". Why doesn't it find "play1()" under Player?

Full code:

```
import random
from time import *


class Colors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


class Player:
    r = random
    coins = 100
    health = 100
    p = 3 #potions.

    def __init__(self):
        random.seed()
        print("init instance variables here")

        def hk1():
            print("Du sprang iväg")

        def hk2():
            print("Du sprang iväg")
            sleep(3)
            print("men du trillar och slår i knät: -20 HP")
            self.health = self.health - 20
            print("Your health is: " + str(self.health), " HP")

        def hkf1():
            if hakan.health <= 0:
                hakan.health = 100
                print("Du besegrade håkan")
                print("Du tar hans droger och säljer det själv till Eleverna: +150 coins")
                print("Your health is ", str(self.health), " HP")
                self.coins = self.coins + 150
                print("You have: ", str(self.coins), " coins")
            else:
                print("Du slår Håkan och gör -25 HP skada på honom.")
                print("Your health is ", str(self.health), " HP")
                print("You have: ", str(self.coins), " coins")
                print("Håkan har ", hakan.health, "left")

        def hkf2():
            print("Håkan besegrade dig: -50 HP")
            print("Your health is ", str(self.health), " HP")
            print("You have: ", str(self.coins), " coins")
            self.coins = self.coins + 150

        def play1():
            choice = random.choice(['flee', 'fall'])
            if choice == 'flee':
                hk1()
            elif choice == 'fall':
                hk2()

        def play2():
            choice = random.choice(['win', 'lose'])
            if choice == 'win':
                hkf1()
            elif choice == "lose":
                hkf2()

    def report_status(self):
        status_message = "Your health is %s, \nCoins left %s" % (self.health, self.coins)
        return status_message


william = Player()
hakan = Player()


def buypotion():
    if william.coins < 0:
        print("You can't afford a potion")
    else:
        william.coins = william.coins - 25
        william.p = Player.p + 1
        print("You bought a potion for 25 coins")
        print("You have ", william.coins, " coins left")
        print("you have ", william.p, " potions")
        print("Your health is now ", str(william.health), " HP")


def drinkpotion():
    if Player.p == 0:
        print("You can't drink any potions.")
        print("You have zero potions left!")
        print("Your health is ", str(william.health), " HP")
    elif william.health >= 250:
        print("Your health is already maxed out. You can't drink a potion.")
        print("you have ", str(william.p), " potions")
        print("Your health is ", str(william.health), " HP")
    else:
        william.health = william.health + 20
        william.p = william.p - 1
        print("you have ", william.p, " potions")
        print("Your health is ", str(william.health), " HP")


def quests():
    quest = input("Choose from quest: 1, 2 or 3 ")
    if quest == "1" or quest == "option 1" or quest == "opt 1":
        quest1()
    elif quest == "2" or quest == "option 2" or quest == "opt 2":
        print(Colors.RED + "ERROR: ERROR: ERROR:" + Colors.ENDC)
        print(Colors.YELLOW + "Quest 2 is not yet added" + Colors.ENDC)
    elif quest == "3" or quest == "option 3" or quest == "opt 3":
        print(Colors.RED + "ERROR: ERROR: ERROR" + Colors.ENDC)
        print(Colors.YELLOW + "Quest 3 is not yet added" + Colors.ENDC)


def quest1():
    print("Du vandrar runt på Rudbeck när du ser Håkan, din samhällslärare, i ett mörkt hörn")
    print("Du väljer att gå närmare för att investigera.")
    print("Håkan står och säljer knark till eleverna.")
    while hakan.health > 0 or william.health > 0 or hk != "Spring" or hk != "spring":
        hk = input("Vad gör du? Spring: Slåss:")
        if hk == "Spring" or hk == "spring":
            Player.play1()
        if hk == "slåss" or hk == "Slåss" or hk == "s":
            Player.play2()


print("Welcome to a poorly made text-based game:")
print("you have ", william.p, " potions")
print("Your health is ", str(william.health), " HP")
print("You have: ", str(william.coins), " coins")

while True:
    print("Commands: add, drink, coins, sleep, quest")
    a = input("Enter a command: ")
    if a == "add" or a == "Add" or a == "buy" or a == "Buy":
        buypotion()
    if a == "drink":
        drinkpotion()
    if a == "quest":
        quests()
```

Comment: You defined your functions within the __init__ function. They are only available in the scope of this function. Remove 4 spaces so that the players function are at the same intendation level as the __init__ function. Furthermore you might want to have an instance of the Player class in your quest function and not calling it statically.

Comment: You defined `play1` and `play2` within the `__init__` method of `Player`, so they're not accessible from outside the class.  Make them class methods if you want to call them externally.